# Positioning three columns on a HTML page using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a basic HTML/CSS Website with a header and three columns below it. But I am not getting a proper alignment. Please help me rectify my code.

```css
    #menu_bar {
      width: 1346px;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    li {
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      border: 4px black solid;
    }
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      color: #ffffff;
      height: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #4169e1;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    a:hover {
      background-color: #000080;
    }
    #icon {
      border: none;
    }
    #first_col {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    #second_col {
      float: left;
      width: 60%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    #third_col {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="menu_bar">
    <ul>
      <li id="icon">
        <img src="blue.jpg" height="60" width="104">
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Messages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="first_col">

    <p>hello</p>

  </div>

  <div id="second_col">

    <p>post here</p>

  </div>

  <div id="third_col">

    <p>friends</p>

  </div>
  <div>
```

The output in the browser comes like this

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

And please help me remove that space before the first column.

Comment: Just a suggestion. When you write <div id="first_col"><p>hello</p></div> you end up with a box in a box: the <p> is inside the <div> and you can simply remove the inner wrapper and just have <div id="first_col">hello</div> You only need a wrapper if you have 2 or more inner contents.

Comment: I was having more inner contents but I removed them for the simplicity of the question.  @frenchie

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bsz3gnu7/2/

Comment: Remove the floats from your columns and add `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` and then make sure there is no whitespace between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the box with hello is positioned in line with the box with the "Blue" img inside it.

use the css [`clear`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) property to seperate the `first_col` div from the `menu_bar` div

so your css declaration for `first_col` would look like this:

```
 #first_col
{
    clear: left;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:708px;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

The css `clear` property

> left - No floating elements allowed on the left side

As pointed out by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27985031/2985029) you will need to remove the `margin-left`from the other two columns to make them appear next to each other.

so you end up with declarations for `second_col` and `third_col` that look like this:

```
#second_col
{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    height:708px;
    background-color:green;
}

#third_col
{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:708px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: You still need to remove the margin from the floating elements

Comment: how do I set the height of any column so that it remains till the end of the page or the end of the text in that column? @9205892

Comment: if you dont require the columns to all be the same height as the content inside them increases then you can use min-height instead of height, that way the column starts off with a height and then can grow with the content

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-left` on `#second_col` and `#third_col`.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your all three div with an another div like this

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first_col">
      <p>hello</p>

    </div>

    <div id="second_col">

      <p>post here</p>

    </div>

    <div id="third_col">

      <p>friends</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

then you can set height of width of wrapper div manually as you required.

Answer (score 0):

just add position:fixed in your css id menu_bar

```css
#menu_bar {
      width: 1346px;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: black;
  position:fixed;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    li {
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      border: 4px black solid;
    }
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      color: #ffffff;
      height: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #4169e1;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    a:hover {
      background-color: #000080;
    }
    #icon {
      border: none;
    }
    #first_col {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    #second_col {
      float: left;
      width: 60%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    #third_col {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      height: 708px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="menu_bar">
    <ul>
      <li id="icon">
        <img src="blue.jpg" height="60" width="104">
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Messages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="first_col">

    <p>hello</p>

  </div>

  <div id="second_col">

    <p>post here</p>

  </div>

  <div id="third_col">

    <p>friends</p>

  </div>
  <div>
```